Why I am unable to rollback my transaction to particular savepoint in plpgsql stored procedure
I am getting error while executing stored procedure on pgadmin at "To" in "Rollback to Savepoint".
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE demo8()
AS $$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO statefis VALUES(83, 'Maharashtra');

   SAVEPOINT abc;

   INSERT INTO statefis VALUES (52, 'KERLA');
   ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT abc;

   INSERT INTO statefis VALUES(35, 'DELHI');
   RELEASE SAVEPOINT abc;
   COMMIT;

   RAISE NOTICE 'Transaction committed successfully':
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


PL/pgSQL doc only lists commit/rollback as options, with some caveats. No savepoint or release allowed: 43.8. Transaction Management
In procedures invoked by the CALL command as well as in anonymous code blocks (DO command), it is possible to end transactions using the commands COMMIT and ROLLBACK. A new transaction is started automatically after a transaction is ended using these commands, so there is no separate START TRANSACTION command. (Note that BEGIN and END have different meanings in PL/pgSQL.)

You cannot use savepoints directly in PL/pgSQL. Instead, you write BEGIN / END blocks with an EXCEPTION handler. Under the hood, this is implemented with subtransactions, just like savepoints.
Your code would look like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE demo8()
AS $$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO statefis VALUES(83, 'Maharashtra');

   /*
    * This sets a savepoint, since there is an EXCEPTION clause.
    * If the INSERT doesn't throw an exception, the subtransaction
    * will get "subcommitted" when execution leaves the block.
    * This is just the same as releasing the savepoint.
    * If PostgreSQL enters the exception handler, the subtransaction
    * will be rolled back.
    */
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO statefis VALUES (52, 'KERLA');
   EXCEPTION
      /* you could capture any other exception as well */
      WHEN unique_violation THEN
         /*
          * As soon as PostgreSQL enters the exception handler,
          * it rolls back the subtransaction.
          * Since that's all you want to happen, add a statement
          * that does nothing.
          */
         NULL;
   END;

   INSERT INTO statefis VALUES(35, 'DELHI'); 

   /*
    * There is little point in this COMMIT.
    * PostgreSQL will commit anyway as soon as the procedure is done.
    */
   COMMIT;

   RAISE NOTICE 'Transaction committed successfully':
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

